# How to confirm whether a block device is not being written anymore after a file write?

Tags: linux, filesystems, dbus, udisks

When I finish writing a file into a device block (for example, `/dev/sda`), I have to wait a while to ensure that the buffer is still not being written anymore to the device. I have to set a callback to trigger a UI event when that finishes.

I have tried using the [`ejectable` property from udisks2](http://storaged.org/doc/udisks2-api/latest/gdbus-org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Drive.html#gdbus-property-org-freedesktop-UDisks2-Drive.Ejectable), and as the documentation says, it's only a guess. It has not been reliable in my experiments.

I have noticed that when the flushing finishes my file manager (Nautilus) lets me unmount the device. What API provides me with such device property?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `fsync` on the file descriptor of the device confirms that the buffer is done writing.